# Insert element on second row

Tags: jquery, function

How can I make a function such that my line "**only every second output**" would be displayed after every second output?

```
$.get(dataurl + '?service=plug1&device1=' + device1 + '&device2=' + device2 + '', function(d){
    var myText = ''
    $(d).find('plug').each(function(){
        myText += 'every output'
        myText += 'only every second output'
    });
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the index:

```
$(d).find('plug').each(function(i) {
    myText += 'every output'

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        myText += 'only every second output'
    }
});
```

Also, don't construct your query string manually. It may not be escaped properly and the alternate way just looks nicer:

```
$.get(dataUrl, {
    service: plug1,
    device1: device1,
    device2: device2
}, function(data) {
    ...
});
```